# Remove Grab Handles from control programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a design surface that could have a lot of different objects I want to show grab Handles when the object is selected and when a new object is selected I want to remove the grab handles and show them on the new object. I found away to make it work not sure if there is a better way but I will show my code here. When I click the button the Grab Handles are removed.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Draw a border and drag handles around the control, on mouse down and up.
    /// Remove if ShowHandles = false
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    private void DrawControlBorder(object sender, Boolean ShowDragHandles)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        //define the border to be drawn, it will be offset by DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2
        //around the control, so when the drag handles are drawn they will be seem
        //connected in the middle.
        Rectangle Border = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2, 
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2), 
            new Size(control.Size.Width + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, 
                control.Size.Height + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        //define the 8 drag handles, that has the size of DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE
        Rectangle NW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, 
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle N = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE/2, 
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle NE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width, 
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle W = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, 
                control.Location.Y + control.Height/2-DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE/2), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle E = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width, 
                control.Location.Y + control.Height / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, 
                control.Location.Y + control.Height), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle S = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE/2, 
                control.Location.Y + control.Height), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width, 
                control.Location.Y + control.Height), 
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));

        //get the form graphic
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

        //draw the border and drag handles
        if (ShowDragHandles) { ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, Border, Color.Gray, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted); }
        else { ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, Border, this.BackColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted);}

        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NW, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, N, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NE, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, W, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, E, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SW, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, S, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SE, ShowDragHandles, ShowDragHandles);
        g.Dispose();
    }

 private void btnHideGrabHandles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawControlBorder(picArchText, false);
        picArchText.Invalidate();
    }
```

When the button is clicked the grab handles are removed. There must be an easier way to remove the handles any thoughts? With several objects on the design surface at any given time I don't want Grab Handles shown when not needed.

Comment: If the code works, then it isn't clear what problem you are asking us to solve.

Comment: I posted it here for others who wanted a similar way to show hide grab handles on a control the actual question - Is there a easier or better way to accomplish this?

Comment: It was already here: [Can't capture Label_Mouse event in Winform C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316756/cant-capture-label-mouse-event-in-winform-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks I will look at that in my searches I found nothing that would do what I wanted.

Comment: Jimi that article was useful they key thing i was missing was the property grid when the property grid changes C# automatically removes the selection rectangle and places it on the new selected control. Now I just need to figure out how to add the grid for use in my application.  Thanks again